# How to get data with @ManyToMany annotated tables?

Tags: sql, hibernate, spring-mvc, many-to-many

My related tables are below.
Person Table

1. id
2. name
3. surname

Location Table

1. id
2. title
3. point

Person_Location Table

1. person_id
2. location_id

I want to get person and location values like this..

---

**id | name | surname | title | point**

1  john | adas  |  my home   |        44,45

  1 | John | adas  |  brother's home |   55,33

How can I get the users and their locations in hibernate?

Comment: in your case `@ManyToMany` means that a person has many Locations and a location belongs to many Persons so the result your trying to get is not compatible with the mapping you've done. foreach Person you will have a list of Locations which means list of titles and list of points

Comment: location is like in swarm.a person have many location, and a location has many person.

Comment: yes that what I told you befor, and you will get more than one location for every person. ah now I get you you want the person to be displayed as many as how much location he has ?

Comment: yeah like you said. many people can been a location in swarm.and A person can been a lot of location in different dates.(foursquare)

Comment: actually I need to get both tables's records by using personId and locationId in "gezi_gezgin" table(Join Table).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this out :

you can get an array of object and you can manipulat them as you want

```
String stringQuery="select p.id,p.name,p.surname,l.title,l.point from person p, location l,person_location pl where "
                + "p.id=pl.person_id and l.id=pl.location_id";
        Query query=entityManager.createNativeQuery(stringQuery);
        List<Object[]> result=query.getResultList();
```

later you can get the person Id by `result.get(i)[0]`

or you can create a custom class which will not be a managed entity:

```
public class customPerson{
id | name | surname | title | point
private int id;
private String name;
private String surname;
private String title;
private String doube point;

//getters&setters

//constructors (required) one default ant one with all your attributes
public CustomPerson(){}
public customPerson(int id,...){
...
}

}
```

later in your Dao you can get the result you want through the custom object:

```
String stringQuery="select p.id,p.name,p.surname,l.title,l.point from person p, location l,person_location pl where "
                + "p.id=pl.person_id and l.id=pl.location_id";
        Query query=entityManager.createNativeQuery(stringQuery,CustomPerson.class);
        List<CustomPerson> result=query.getResultList();
```

Answer (score 0):

// In Person class:

```
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="Person_Location",
        joinColumns=
            @JoinColumn(name="person_id", referencedColumnName="ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns=
            @JoinColumn(name="location_id", referencedColumnName="ID")
        )
    public Set<Locations> getLocations() { return locations; }
```

// In Location:

```
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="locations")
    public Set<Person> getPersons() { return persons; }
```

Comment: I have already that fields and the annotations like you wrote.my point is that I want to get the records both Person and Location table using Person_Locations table.

Answer (score 0):

In Person class

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="person")
    public Set<personLocations> getPersonLocation { return personLocations; }
```

In Location class

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="location")
    public Set<personLocations> getPersonLocation { return personLocations; }
```

In personLocations

```
 @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="person_ID")
    public Person getPerson() { return person; }

 @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="location_ID")
    public Location getlocation() { return location; }
```

Comment: I have used @ManyToMany annotation in my person class like below. As I said location is like in swarm.a person have many location, and a location has many person. http://paste.ubuntu.com/17068410/

Comment: mapping between location table and person table can be many to many , but as per my understanding from column listed in location_person table mapping between locationPerson and person will be many to one one to many only